# Azure CI Playwright Webserver is not starting

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-devops, e2e-testing, playwright

When I run the Playwright test on Azure CI pipeline.I'm get timeout issue, I increased the timeout, but I think the problem is in the webserver is not starting or can't listen to.It works locally.

Error that I get

```
Generating script.
Script contents: shell
npx playwright test--config = playwright.config.ts
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe" /D /E:ON /V:OFF /S /C "CALL "D:\\a_temp\\dbde5bf8-d802-451d-9098-eea49ccf3940.cmd""
\[WebServer\] - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...

Error: Timed out waiting 120000ms from config.webServer.

To open last HTML report run:

npx playwright show-report

\##\[error\]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Run Playwright Test Command Line
```

Here is the webserver configuration in the playwright.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
    testDir: './e2e-tests',
    fullyParallel: true,
    forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
    retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
    workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
    reporter: 'html',
    use: {
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:4200',
    },

    projects: [
        {
            name: 'chromium',
            use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
        },
    ],
    
    webServer: {
        command: 'ng serve',
        url: 'http://localhost:4200',
        timeout: 2 \* 60 \* 1000,
        reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    },

});
```